# Form Code: How to get submit button next to text box

Tags: html, css, forms

I just can't figure out to get the "submit" button to the right of the text box for the form found at the top of the loop on this page: http://www.babysavers.com.

The code I'm using is here:

```
<center>
<div style="width: 625px; height: 70px;  border-style: dotted; border-color: #d7345a; border-width: 1px; padding: 5px;">
<form action="http://www.feedblitz.com/f/f.fbz?AddNewUserDirect&amp;ajax=4" method="POST" name="FeedBlitz_9fe455b8521611e29f67003005ce8903">
<h3>Join over 8,900 subscribers! Enter your email below for FREE Updates:</h3>
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="EMAIL" value="" maxlength="64"  size="65">
<input type="hidden" name="EMAIL_" value="" maxlength="64" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="EMAIL_ADDRESS" value="" maxlength="64" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="FEEDID" value="873069" /> <input type="hidden" name="cids" value="1" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="PUBLISHER" value="24085942" />
<input onclick="FeedBlitz_9fe455b8521611e29f67003005ce8903s(this.form);" type="button" value="Subscribe!" />
</form></div><script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">// < ![CDATA[
// < ![CDATA[
// < ![CDATA[
// < ![CDATA[
function FeedBlitz_9fe455b8521611e29f67003005ce8903i(){var x=document.getElementsByName('FeedBlitz_9fe455b8521611e29f67003005ce8903');for(i=0;i<x .length;i++){x[i].EMAIL.style.display='block';
x[i].action='http://www.feedblitz.com/f/f.fbz?AddNewUserDirect';}}
function FeedBlitz_9fe455b8521611e29f67003005ce8903s(v){v.submit();}FeedBlitz_9fe455b8521611e29f67003005ce8903i();
// ]]></script><br></center>
```

I know my code is sloppy, but all I want to do is line up the Submit button so it's to the right of the text box, not underneath it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just looked at this page and the search button is to the right.

Answer (score 4):

Set your display to inline rather than none:

```
style="display: inline;"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this change (display: inline):

```
<input type="text" size="65" maxlength="64" value="" name="EMAIL" style="display: inline;">
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you! This, combined with removing a LOT of my messy code worked perfectly!